# how to generate random timestamp in sql query withing range for h2 database?

Tags: java, sql, timestamp, h2, date-arithmetic

I have this db table in an H2 database called `"mytable"` and two of the fields have the type `"TIMESTAMP"`. [image]

I have writen the following query in order to update the table:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET START_TIME_ = "2018-01-01 01:01:01" , END_TIME_ = "2020-01-01 01:01:01";
```

I was wondering how could I modify my query so that it generates at the START_TIME_ and END_TIME_  fields random dates between `2018-01-01 01:01:01` and `2020-01-01 01:01:01`. As the H2 timestamp  is not a UNIX timestamp I am unsure how to go about it. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

In H2 1.4.200 you can use

```
UPDATE mytable SET
    START_TIME_ = @T := TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 01:01:01'
        + RAND() * INTERVAL '730 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND,
    END_TIME_ = @T + (TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 01:01:01' - @T) * RAND();
```

`INTERVAL '730 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND` can be replaced with the subtraction operation between high and low bounds `(TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 01:01:01' - TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 01:01:01')`.

Note that distribution of `START_TIME_` is linear here, but distribution of `END_TIME_` is not. If such distribution doesn't satisfy your needs, you need to use some more complex expressions, but you can use the same datetime arithmetic operations in them.

Please also note that inline variable assignment syntax uses the `:=`  operator and not the `=` operator.

Comment: thank you so much! it shows me tho that there is a syntax error somewhere which I cant spot

Comment: also what is the @T doing exactly? could you maybe elaborate? perhaps it would help solve the syntax error

Comment: You can create named variables (prefixed with `@`) in your current session and use them in various expressions and commands to store some values.